# Cannot mount NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

I have one HHD with multiple NTFS partitions, I didn't use that drive for about year, but now I would like to get that data from OS partition back.

It looks like:
[image: KDE Partition Manager]

When I run:

```
sudo mount --verbose /dev/sdc2 /home/neon/test
```

I get:

```
Failed to read last sector (524398583): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I tried to open that partition with Dolphin and with Windows explorer too, but with no success.

Comment: Think you will have to use a recent windows OS.  Windows recently has a bad habit of using fast boot, that tends to lock NTFS partitions from being read from linux.  Solution is to turn fast boot off and shutdown windows completely

Comment: @crip659 But partition with Windows is deleted, that partition labed as OS is just backup from old Windows and it cannot be booted.

Comment: If you have some free space, would recommend to install windows.  It would be a lot simpler and easier to do from a Windows OS, can always be deleted after.  Might need 'WoeUSB' if you need to burn a windows install disk from linux.  Are those partitions from Win 8 or 10, or from Win 7?

Comment: @crip656 Partitions are from Windows 7, and I just put that HDD into Windows 7 machine and it sees as primary drive with 100% free space, but I cannot open it, because Windows requires to format it, Windows says that it doesn't contain known file system and it may be corrupted, but other partitions on that drive works just fine.

Comment: This getting past my knowledge to help, but maybe googling on how to fix ntfs file will help